# iOS Transition animation

Tags: ios, animation

I'm trying to create a transparent modal popover animation, which I got working except when I rotate the view, it stays the same size. Could somebody point me to the right direction? Below is the animation code I'm currently using

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIView *inView = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    [inView addSubview:toVC.view];

    CGRect screenRect = fromVC.view.bounds;
    [toVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenRect.size.height, fromVC.view.frame.size.width, fromVC.view.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
        animations:^{

          [toVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fromVC.view.frame.size.width, fromVC.view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
          [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code with a combination auto-layout and the view resizes fine for me. Just to make sure, is this what you are trying to achieve?

[image]

**EDIT**
Here are the steps I followed to implement this

1. Add a segue to the view controller in the storyboard
   [image]
2. Create the transition class (say MyTransitionClass).
3. Add UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate to the parent view controller
4. Implement the animationControllerForPresentedController method in the parent view controller like so

   ```
   -(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source{
   return [[MyTransitionClass alloc] init];
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, but also I would like your white to be transparent and show the green. I just dont understand why it won't rotate I just set the view in loadView:

Comment: Maybe I use the wrong code in presentation? So how do you present it? Using the custom transition?

Comment: You use UIModalPresentationPopover which is defined in iOS 8. I use custom since I've to support iOS 7.